# Is there a "running sushi"/"sushi train" anywhere in Lithuania?

Tags: food-and-drink, lithuania

My son was really excited when we visited a "running sushi" restaurant in Germany. Now I try to find one in Lithuania, where we actually live. There are a lots of great sushi restaurant in Vilnius, but I did not find information, if one of them present their creations on a flat conveyor.

Is there a "running sushi" restaurant in Vilnius, or more general in Lithuania?

Comment: You mean a "sushi train"? A restaurant with a conveyor belt with little plates going around and you pick the plates and they bill you by counting them at the end?

Comment: Yes :) I am sorry, if I chose the wrong translation. In Germany it is called "running sushi" and does not have a "german" name.

Comment: Common names are "sushi train" or "conveyor belt sushi", but my Google-fu doesn't yield anything in Vilnius or Lithuania. Closest Yo! Sushi in Oslo, quite a hike!

Comment: @jcaron hike and boat tour ^^ over the baltic sea...

Answer (score 7):

the term is "Kaiten-Zushi", a sushi restaurant where a plate of sushi is placed on a rotating conveyor belt that moves through the restaurant, passing each table and seat. Customers often can request special orders.

Unfortunately searching for "kaiten zushi Lietuvoje" nor for "Kaiten-Sushi in Lithuania" didn't come up with any significant result.

the closest Sushi Train (Kaiten-Zushi) restaurant listing I found was https://restaurantguru.com/Sushi-King-Vilnius-5#gallery, which seems to be a buffet-table style belt. (Sushi King, Kalvarijų Street, 149, Vilnius.)

When researching to answer your questions, I found some inspiring sites, with more information on some "traditional" Sushi places.

Lithuanian: Use automatic translation if needed:

- https://www.mzirafos.lt/sushi-kaune-rytietiska-virtuve/
  (Sushi in Kaunas: TOP10 places according to visitor rating)
- https://kaunozinios.lt/autorinis/kur-valgyti-sushi-kaune_110849.html
  (Where to eat sushi in Kaunas?)

English:

- https://wanderlog.com/list/geoCategory/85211/sushi (The 18 best sushi restaurants and sushi bars in Kaunas)

Locations:

- https://www.google.com/maps/search/sushi+Lietuvoje/